# Problem with implementing sql queries into Javafx

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I wanted to ask a question about implementing SQL queries into a JavaFX application, specifically, I've been trying to create an "employee" application that connects to a MySQL database hosted in localhost. I'm using a DAO pattern to do this and the code is apparently right, the only problem I'm having is that I keep getting errors when trying to add a new employee to the table. Specifically, I'm getting an SQL syntax error and I have no idea what is wrong with the code.

I'll put the code for my EmployeeDAO class down there, please ignore the SQL errors in all the methods (I haven't corrected it yet), the method I already corrected and is still giving me problems is the insertEmp() method.

```
package Model;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import Util.DBUtil;
import java.sql.*;



public class EmployeeDAO {

//Select an Employee

public static Employee searchEmployee (String empId) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String selectStmt = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeId="+empId;

    try{
        ResultSet rsEmp = DBUtil.dbExecuteQuery(selectStmt);
        Employee employee = getEmployeeFromResultSet(rsEmp);
        return employee;
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("While Searching An Employee With "+empId+" Id, An Error Occurred");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

}

private static Employee getEmployeeFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
    Employee emp = null;
    if(rs.next()){
        emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("EMPLOYEE_ID"));
        emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
        emp.setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
        emp.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        emp.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("PHONE_NUMBER"));
        emp.setHireDate(rs.getDate("HIRE_DATE"));
        emp.setJobId(rs.getString("JOB_ID"));
        emp.setSalary(rs.getInt("SALARY"));
        emp.setCommissionPct(rs.getDouble("COMMISSION_PCT"));
        emp.setManagerId(rs.getInt("MANAGER_ID"));
        emp.setDepartmentId(rs.getInt("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
    }
    return emp;
}

//Select Employees
public static ObservableList<Employee> searchEmployees() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
    String selectStmt="SELECT * FROM employees";
    try{
        ResultSet rsEmps = DBUtil.dbExecuteQuery(selectStmt);
        ObservableList<Employee> empList = getEmployeeList(rsEmps);
        return empList;
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("SQL Select Operation Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
//Select * from employees operation
private static ObservableList<Employee> getEmployeeList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
    ObservableList<Employee> empList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    while(rs.next()){
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("EMPLOYEE_ID"));
        emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
        emp.setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
        emp.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        emp.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("PHONE_NUMBER"));
        emp.setHireDate(rs.getDate("HIRE_DATE"));
        emp.setJobId(rs.getString("JOB_ID"));
        emp.setSalary(rs.getInt("SALARY"));
        emp.setCommissionPct(rs.getDouble("COMMISSION_PCT"));
        emp.setManagerId(rs.getInt("MANAGER_ID"));
        emp.setDepartmentId(rs.getInt("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
        empList.add(emp);
    }
    return empList;
}

//Update an employee's email address
public static void updateEmpEmail(String empId, String empEmail) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String updateStmt = "BEGIN\n" +
                    "   UPDATE employees\n" +
                    "      SET EMAIL = '" + empEmail + "'\n" +
                    "    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = " + empId + ";\n" +
                    "   COMMIT;\n" +
                    "END;";
    try{
        DBUtil.dbExecuteQuery(updateStmt);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("An Error Occurred While Updating The Information");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}

public static void deleteEmpWithId(String empId) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String updateStmt = "BEGIN\n" +
                    "   DELETE FROM employees\n" +
                    "         WHERE employee_id ="+ empId +";\n" +
                    "   COMMIT;\n" +
                    "END;";
    try{
        DBUtil.dbExecuteQuery(updateStmt);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("An Error Occurred While Deleting An Employee With Id: "+empId);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
}

 }

 public static void insertEmp(String name, String lastName, String email) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String updateStmt = "BEGIN\n" +
                    " INSERT INTO employees ('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'HIRE_DATE', 'JOB_ID')\n" +
                    " VALUES\n" +
                    " (?, ?, ?, SYSDATE, 'IT_PROG');\n" +
                    " END;";
     try{
        DBUtil.dbPreparedStatement(updateStmt, name, lastName, email);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("An Error Occurred While Adding A New Employee To The Table");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
}

}
```

I'll also add down here the code that uses the insertEmp method.

```
public static void dbPreparedStatement(String sqlStmt, String name, String lastName, String email) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try{
        dbConnect();
        stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setString(2, lastName);
        stmt.setString(3, email);
        stmt.execute();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error Occured At ExecutePreparedStatement Operation");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    dbDisconnect();
}
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes around the column names i.e. just use FIRST_NAME instead of 'FIRST_NAME' and so on

Comment: @shree.pat18 I fixed the column names as you said, also fixed the SYSDATE into SYSDATE() and for some reason it kept getting me a syntax error. Took away the BEGIN and END lines and now it's working properly, no idea why though

Answer (score 0):

As shree mentioned, I made a mistake when writing down column names, I fixed that, also fixed an error regarding the SYSDATE() function being written mistakingly as only SYSDATE. The SQL still wouldn't work, so I took out the BEGIN and END lines and it works fine now, no idea why though.